# PYTHON: Pandas DF column as datetime

Tags: python, datetime, pandas

I am trying to get pandas to recognise a datetime when reading a tab delimited txt file.

```
data = pd.read_csv('1.txt', header=0, parse_dates=True, 
                   date_parser=lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x, format='%Y%m%d%H%M'))
```

The format of my datetime is always '%Y%m%j%H%M' and I have tried also using

```
infer_datetime_format=True
```

The data is as:

```
,id,date,mmhr

0,1,200709270000,0
```

How can I get pandas.read_csv to recognise datetime on import?

Many thanks

Comment: `parse_dates=True` means pandas looks for a date in the index.  Is that where your date is? Also, is this really what you mean: `format='%Y%m%j%H%M'`, `%j` and not `%d`?

Comment: Ahh no the dates are in the second column and yes mean '%d': see edit.

Comment: So, do you still have a problem? And if so, what happens?

Comment: It runs ok, but dates are of dtype int64 should they not be datetime64?

Comment: Try to say `parse_dates=[1]`.

Comment: perfect. add answer if you want rep. Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your date columns looks like an int to pandas.  pandas expects dates to look like strings, as in `1990-1-1`, not `1990101`.

You need to use `parse_dates = [2]`

```
pd.read_csv('1.txt', parse_dates=[2])
```